# Clear/Reset persistent variables in lambda/implicit function

Tags: matlab, lambda

i have a little problem with the output of a performance-plot during the training of a neural network, using matlab. I am using a **lambda function (plot_train_loss)** to plot the training progress, which gets a parameter **"info"** as a passing argument:

```
options = trainingOptions('sgdm', ...
    'MaxEpochs',num_epochs,...
    'InitialLearnRate',learning_rate, ...
    'ValidationData',imdsTest, ...
    'ValidationFrequency',validationFrequency, ...
    'Verbose',false, ...
    'Plots','none',...
    'OutputFcn',@(info)plot_train_loss(info,3), ...
    'MiniBatchSize', mini_batch_size);


[net,info] = trainNetwork(imdsTrain,my_net,options);
```

This also works wonderfully. Well, at least for the first time. However, as soon as I want to train again, the function remembers the persistent function variables (train_iteration,train_loss,train_accuracy,bestValAccuracy,valLag) and the plot of the previous trainings is the initial output for the next training. Is there a way to clear the implicit persistent variables within the plotting function after the training?

Here's some code from the "plot_train_loss" function:

```
function stop  = plot_train_loss(info,N)

% initialize persitent variable in order to save the past values
persistent train_iteration
persistent train_loss
persistent train_accuracy
% Keep track of the best validation accuracy and the number of validations for which
% there has not been an improvement of the accuracy.
persistent bestValAccuracy
persistent valLag

global training_figure;
global num_iterations;

stop = false;

% check in which state the training is
% if start: do nothing
if info.State == "start"
    info.Iteration  = {};
    info.TrainingLoss = {};
    info.TrainingAccuracy = {};
    bestValAccuracy = 0;
    valLag = 0;
    return
end

% assign values of training to variable
train_iteration(info.Iteration) = info.Iteration;
train_loss(info.Iteration) = info.TrainingLoss;
train_accuracy(info.Iteration) = info.TrainingAccuracy;

% plot training progress

t = tiledlayout(2,1);

nexttile;
plot(train_iteration,train_loss,'g');
xlim([0 num_iterations]);
max_train_loss = max(train_loss(:)) + 0.2;
ylim([0 max_train_loss]);
grid on;
title('Training loss');

nexttile;
plot(train_iteration,train_accuracy,'b');
xlim([0 num_iterations]);
ylim([0 100]);
grid on;
title('Training accuracy');
```

So, the function is "recalled" in two different cases:

- it gets recalled within a singular training cycle: --> do not clear variables
- it gets recalled after a previous training cycle: --> do clear variables

or in this scheme: (r: recall ; | = next cycle)

```
<-----cycle 1----------><-----cycle 2----------->
<----------------------clear------------------- ->
r; r; r; r; r; r; r; r; | r; r; r; r; r; r; r; r;
```

Hope someone can help me with this issue, it's really a little bit tricky

Comment: But that is the entire goal o fmaking them persistent, right? do not make them persistent? In any case, maybe `clearvars` helps?

Answer (score 1):

```
clear plot_train_loss
```

will clear the function and all its persistent variables from memory. The next time the function is called, it will be read from file and compiled again, and its persistent variables will be created anew.